# Surface integral and the divergence theorem

Tags: integration, physics

I haven't done a surface integral in a while so I am asking to get this checked.

[image]

$\mathbf{F} = \langle x, y, z\rangle$ and the surface is $z = xy + 1$ where $0\leq x,y\leq 1$.

$\hat{\mathbf{n}} = \nabla f/ \lvert\nabla f\rvert = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\langle 1, 1, 1\rangle$

$dS = \frac{\lvert\nabla f\rvert dxdy}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}} = \sqrt{3}dxdy$

$\mathbf{F}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(x+y+z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(x+y+xy + 1)$

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1(x + y + xy + 1)dxdy = \frac{9}{4}
$$

However, when I used the divergence theorem, I obtained:

$$
\int_S(\mathbf{F}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}})dS = \int_V(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F})dV
$$
and $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F} = 3$
so
$$
\int 3dV = 3V = 3\frac{5}{4} = \frac{15}{4}
$$

Which one is wrong or are both incorrect?  If so, what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid neither is correct. You confused derivatives of $\mathbf F$ with calculating the surface normal. The Divergence Theorem does not apply, as you do not have a closed surface (so there's no volume $V$ enclosed). And to compute the surface integral you need to compute
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \mathbf F(\mathbf g(x,y))\cdot \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf g}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf g}{\partial y}\right) \,dx\,dy\,,$$
where $\mathbf g(x,y) = (x,y,xy+1)$.
This becomes
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (1-xy)\,dx\,dy = \frac34\,.$$

Comment: Well, perhaps you didn't fully state the problem. In your terse statement, you gave us $\mathbf F$ and you said "and the surface is ..." :)

Comment: Forget the cube. Make a closed surface by adding in three faces (bottom, right, back in your picture). The total flux outward across all four faces is $3$ times the volume enclosed. So you now need to subtract the flux across the three faces you've appended to answer your original question.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: The integral of divergence over the region, yes. But this gives the flux across *all* of the bounding surface. Your top surface is only part of what needs to be a closed surface.